# How to conditionally select rows to display

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Data frame:

```
Detection Location  Detection Date & Time   
CV234   22/09/2018 5:16:07 PM
CV23    23/09/2018 3:01:12 AM
CV23    23/09/2018 7:06:44 PM   
CV23    30/09/2018 9:52:35 PM   
CV23    23/09/2018 8:46:25 AM   
CV23    23/09/2018 10:52:54 AM  
CV23    23/09/2018 5:47:44 AM   
CV234   13/09/2018 6:16:58 PM   
CV23    8/09/2018 2:24:19 PM
CV23    9/09/2018 1:45:46 PM
CV234   7/09/2018 10:26:59 PM
CV23    8/09/2018 1:12:42 AM
CV23    8/09/2018 4:18:17 PM
CV23    7/09/2018 9:32:54 AM
```

I want to conditionally pick up only those rows where within 1 hours there have been 3 values of detection. Like within that hour there should be 3 values in the detection location column.

Comment: Are you aware that your example data **doesn't** have any case with your condition? Besides, what have you tried?

Comment: @Chris = It has cases, But its edited by moderator and now its flat, there are some cells in detection location column where there is no value as there have not been detection in that period.

Comment: By the data which  we can see right now, the question still stands valid. How to choose an hour of frame where the at least 3 detection lie . There might be hours where there would be less than 3 detection.

Comment: @ShrutiGaur - Can you change sample data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It means at least one value in output from your sample data by your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert column to datetimes and then count number of values per hour with [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), [`Resampler.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.transform.html) and [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html) for Series with same size like original `DataFrame`, so possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) :

```
df['Detection Date & Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Detection Date & Time'])

s = df.resample('H',on='Detection Date & Time')['Detection Location'].transform('size')

df1 = df[s.sort_index() == 3]
print (df1)
```

Comment: Done ! Thank ton

Comment: sorry i checked again and there is one problem. I needed only those detection picked which are occurring thrice (3 times) within one hour. This code is picking detection occurring thrice in one day, whether occurring in one hour or more. How should i put condition for one hour only.

Comment: @Shruri Gaur Thete is resample by `H`, it means hours, why do you think it is by day?

Comment: yes thanks. i made a little change of df1 = df[s.sort_index() >= 3] so i got more than that as well under all other conditions. I was confused when i was testing the code. Thanks ton. Accepted the answer :).